# save image in oracle database with oledb provider

Tags: c#, .net-1.0

i want to save image file in oracle database in blob data type field,but because OleDbType type(OleDbType.Binary) does not support blob data type , when I am trying to save file it is not receiving file more then  25kb size image file and showing error message "ORA-01460: unimplemented or unreasonable conversion requested".so please help me to overcome this problem i want to save image file as binary format with more then 3 mb size image in oracle databae

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should change data type to text and save them encoded to base64. It works for me in MSSQL2005